# Overloading function templates and inherited arguments

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

This code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};

class B : public A {};

class C {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void x(const T& t) {
        std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
    }

    void x(const A*& a) {
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
    }

    void x(const int& a) {
        std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void y(T t) {
        std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
    }

    void y(A* a) {
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
    }

    void y(int a) {
        std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void z(const T& t) {
        std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
    }
};

// Does not compile
// template <>
// void C::z(const A*& a) {
//  std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
// }

template <>
void C::z(const int& a) {
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    C c;
    c.x(new A());
    c.x(new B());
    c.x(1);
    c.y(new A());
    c.y(new B());
    c.y(1);
    c.z(new A());
    c.z(new B());
    c.z(1);
}
```

Prints:

```
template
template
int
a
template
int
template
template
int
```

I have the following questions about that:

- Why does `void C::z(const int& a)` compile but `void C::z(const A*& a)` does not?
- What is a reasonable solution to problem? I need to have a templated function for generically handling a wide variety of arguments, but a large set of classes with a common base needs to be handled specifically. I need some approach that will print `a a int`.

Edit: Thanks to the suggestion of @AndyG I was able to resolve this with some type_traits and the code below:

```
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_base_of.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/remove_pointer.hpp>

#include <iostream>

class A {};

class B : public A {};

class C {
public:
    template <typename T>
    typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_base_of<A, typename boost::remove_pointer<T>::type>, void>::type x(const T& t) {
        std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
    }

    void x(A*const& a) {
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
    }

    void x(const int& a) {
        std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    C c;
    c.x(new A());
    c.x(new B());
    c.x(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is because a `const` on a pointer type is a little weird.

What you want is this:

```
template <>
void C::z( A*const&  a) {
  std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
}
```

`const` needs to be read right to left. Since `z` accepts a `T&`, when you want to specialize for `A*` you need to place the `const` after `A*` instead of in front.

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t1DFXbzY0fKv8tLl)